# Save logical expressions to file that can be evaluated later

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an app that allows users to sumbit logical expressions. The same app will also evaluate these logical expressions later, referencing variables in memory. What is the general approach to a problem of this nature?

```
Variables in memory (example)
Variable   Type      Value
height     string    tall
plans      integer   3

Examples of logical expressions a user may have entered:
height = "tall"
plans > 3
Left(height, 1) = "s"
height = "tall" AND plans > 3
```

I've considered using regular expressions, reflection, or writing a compiler or parser.
As all these options are "difficult" for someone of my experience, I was wondering which would make the most sense for my problem or if there is a more suitable method?

Comment: What would happen for an expression like `plans = "tall"`?

Comment: Preferably it would evaluate to a third value besides true/false, or throw an error. I could check for type consistency when the user creates expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store expressions in Excel's syntax and use Excel.Evaluate

Use a boolean to mark which variable values are Numeric and should omit quotes in the logic string.

Use a metacharacter to denote variables (i.e. the "@" char), and replace them with their values prior to evaluating.
This approach is easy to implement and will give users access to Excel's formulae.

```
 Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim variables As DataTable
 Dim initialString As String 'this is the logic string
    For Each row As DataRow In variables.Rows
        If DirectCast(row.Item("Numeric"), Boolean) Then
            initialString = Strings.Replace(initialString, _
                "@" & DirectCast(row.Item("Variable"), String), _
                DirectCast(row.Item("VarValue"), String))
        Else
            initialString = Strings.Replace(initialString, _
                "@" & DirectCast(row.Item("Variable"), String), _
                """" & DirectCast(row.Item("VarValue"), String) & """")
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(xlApp.Evaluate(initialString))
```

Comment: IIRC, this requires that the user has Excel/Office installed. Make sure to list any dependencies.